# Get file contents without file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl

I'm not allowed to use file_get_contents. Originally I got the file contents by simply doing this:

```
$filepath = $_FILES['resume-attachment']['tmp_name'];
$filecontent = file_get_contents($filepath);
$encodedFile = base64_encode($filecontent);
```

Unfortunately, it's not allowed.

```
$filepath = $_FILES['resume-attachment']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['resume-attachment']['name'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $filepath);
$filecontent = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$encodedFile = base64_encode($filecontent);
```

The code above is my attempt at using cURL. I get the filename uploaded, so I get some reaction, but the uploaded file is 0.0 bytes of size... which is not correct. I would think that perhaps the issue could be that I shouldn't treat `$filepath` as a URL, but what would the alternative be? I should also mention that I'm not trying to post it from this code. I simply want to get the file contents, and then encode it. It's part of an XML string later on.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use `file_get_contents` exactly? What is it that you would like to accomplish here aside from placing arbitrary restrictions on how it is to be accomplished?

Comment: I'm just not allowed by my host. I've tried enabling it in my php.ini file, but no luck.

Comment: You mean enabling `allow_url_fopen`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Oh, OK, well that's good, because fortunately they have nothing to do with using `file_get_contents` in this way.

Comment: It's still not working, regardless.

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful metric by which to help debug your problem though. You're stating that "*regardless of the reason why, `file_get_contents` is not a reasonable solution to your problem*". I'm stating that "*if I can understand the reason I can eliminate the need to seek an alternative solution*". See the difference? How about telling me what error you get when using `file_get_contents` rather than telling me it's not going to work? Please see [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for reference.